# Css not applying to ::after correctly

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a custom class with ::after but not all elements have it applied.

[image]

As you can see the email element hasn't the border (::after). This occurs both in Chrome and Firefox.

This is the html for each element:

```
<div class="content-contact-info">
    <div class="content-contact-info-icon">
        <img src="https://cpanel.appmatic.nulltilus.com/images/icons/controlpanel/gallery/ic_info_black_48dp.png">
    </div>

    <div class="content-contact-text">
        <div class="content-contact-info-title">
            Las copas gemelas
        </div>
the ::after
        <div class="content-contact-info-subtitle">
            Carrer de Xàtiva, Valencia
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css:

```
.mobile-container > .mobile-content .content-contact-info {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

    position: relative;

    padding: 14px 0;
}

.mobile-container > .mobile-content .content-contact-info::after {
    content: '';

    width: 600px;
    height: 1px;

    margin-left: calc(100% - 600px);

    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.mobile-container > .mobile-content .content-contact-info > .content-contact-info-icon {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;

    padding: 25px;
}

.mobile-container > .mobile-content .content-contact-info > .content-contact-info-icon > img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.mobile-container > .mobile-content .content-contact-info > .content-contact-text > .content-contact-info-title, .mobile-container > .mobile-content .content-contact-info > .content-contact-text > .content-contact-info-subtitle {
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 60px;
}

.mobile-container > .mobile-content .content-contact-info > .content-contact-text > .content-contact-info-title {
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.mobile-container > .mobile-content .content-contact-info > .content-contact-text > .content-contact-info-subtitle {
    color: #797979;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

    padding-top: 7px;
}
```

If the height inside the ::after is set to > 1px, it works.

Comment: try to use position: absoulte on your :after element  and then use top and letf to choose the correct position

Comment: Same result with position:absolute

Comment: I've created a codepen with the code you provided but I guess you have missed some CSS https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/wPxoEq please provide full HTML and CSS

Comment: Yup, there's something up with the email html and/or css which is missing.

Comment: This is the pen with all html and css https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEjpdq The content is loaded via js

Comment: Ok, in codepen I can see that all it's working fine but It has not sense, I've just copied the html from the firefox console!

Comment: Your HTML shown above does not match your CSS. Your example markup within the question must reproduce the problem. [mcve] Codepen is not acceptable.

Comment: I've posted the answer below, I need to wait 2 days to accept it, sry for the inconveniences

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I was using zoom navigator to 70% in order to fit content in the page (testing) and as I can see, navigator can't render 1px div with 70% zoom. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, zoom can be tricky, I report here an example:

If you have an element with height set to 30px, then a 90% zoom works ok, because this is 27px, but a zoom of 75% not anymore, because this is 22.50 px.

Be careful!